# Use composition of functions to derive the function that relates oral dosage to the amount of drug that reaches the sinus cavity.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAEJA.png

How does the book go from $$\frac{2x}{x+8}-1 \Rightarrow \frac{2x-(x+8)}{x+8}$$

Comment: 1 = $x+8\over x+8$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is that $$1=\frac{x+8}{x+8}$$ if $x\neq -8$.

Comment: So essentially, one needs to subtract the one from the rest of the expression. You do this by getting a common denominator of x+8 by allowing 1 to equal x+8/x+8 you can combine the parts of the expression to end up with 2x-(x+8) / x+8 ? Thank you for the quick reply.